# Extension make deference performance in angular js

Tags: angularjs

I am developing web application using angular js with laravel 4.2 so, Anugular js is for front-end and laravel is just for getting data from database can some one please let me know in angular js whatever the template file is used and having extension like .php or .html so does it make deference in performance..?

Comment: Please share some more context around your question.

Comment: @Chandermani : i am developing web application using angular js with laravel 4.2 so can you please suggest me which extension i used for my view .php or .html ..?

Comment: @Chandermani : i see so many site where they are using .html extension so does it make deference in performance...?

Comment: Please add this detail to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When starting out with Angular it can be tempting to do "double templating" - using templates on the server side and client side. Think of your Angular application as disconnected from your backend as an iOS or Android application.

I recommend only templating on the client side. This can improve performance in two ways: 1) you can use a CDN to distribute your front end application since it's entirely static. 2) Even if you don't use a CDN you can avoid the processing involved in server side templating - a request for a static resource is much faster than a dynamic one.

To summarize, if using php it will be tempting to do double templating. Even if you manage to avoid double templating a request for a php file will run through the php interpreter. This requires more processing time when compared to serving a static html resource.